# What DotNetVersion to use for "No Managed Code"

Tags: iis, ms-release-management

In IIS you can select "No Managed Code". But how to select this using Release Management or command-line tools?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "No Managed Code" you should just NOT fill the value. That way it'll automatically select "No Managed Code".

Source: [Google Books: IIS 7.0](https://books.google.nl/books?id=SOLc0KuBRvcC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=%22DotNetVersion%22%20iis%20%22no%20managed%20code%22&source=bl&ots=_vWMZgHhkE&sig=bq8R9L-OZBlSOYl6y5CX8WCHCQ8&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAWoVChMIhIj6rvOKyQIVBoYPCh3IVAGX#v=onepage&q=%22DotNetVersion%22%20iis%20%22no%20managed%20code%22&f=false)